# Accommodate HTTPS Connections in HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using HttpURLConnection to do POST requests.

I read HttpsURLConnection extends HttpURLConnection with support for https-specific features such as SSL

If HttpsURLConnection use same methods in HttpURLConnection(parent class), it super calls the methods from HttpURLConnection.

```
        URL url = new URL(callBackUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(setConnectTimeout);
        connection.setReadTimeout(setConnectTimeout);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

        OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        os.write(data.toString());

        os.flush();
        os.close();

        if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));

            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(output);

            }
        }
```

However, when I use a HTTPS Url, I keep getting the error below;

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1964) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:328) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

Question, how do I handle both SSL and non SSL connection as is the case in PHP where when using CURL, you set ignore SSL check

`curl_setopt($cHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($cHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);`

I am on Linux, Spring framework and TomCat Web Server.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

For the `HTTPS` things to work first, you would need to add your SSL Certificate into your Java's trust store... For that, you'll have to follow the following steps:

Generally your truststore file of the used JVM would be located at `%JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts`.

You might first take a look if your certificate is already added to the truststore by running the following command:

```
keytool -list -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
```

Once you confirm that it is not added to your Java trust store, you can use the following command to add it:

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias <AliasName> -file   <certificate> -keystore <KeystoreFile> -storepass <Password>
```

Once the following steps are done, you should be able to run your program without running into your HTTPS related issues.

Hope that helps!

**EDIT-1**:
The above method helps adding an SSL Certificate on a Windows environment. Please check the following [article](https://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/connect/content/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/adding-trusted-root-certificates-to-the-server-1605.html) for a Linux variant...

Comment: I tried running `keytool -list -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts"`


Response `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

On running the second command, `keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias <AliasName> -file   <certificate> -keystore <KeystoreFile> -storepass <Password>`

I keep getting `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'`

Comment: Updated my answer to show the same process on different OS variants, kindly check that!

Comment: Modifying the JVM cacerts file is a very very bad idea as it first affects all Java applications on that system (can cause vulnerability in other app) and second you have to perform the modification again and again every time you update the JRE. Instead create an app-specific trust store and use it within your application.